# How can you safely format/round axis labels so no label appears twice

Tags: javascript, algorithm, charts, axis-labels

I'm writing a custom chart that has two tweaked axes.
I want to display rounded numbers to the axes, like

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `[950, 2050, 3000, 4500]` | `["1K", "2K", "3K", "5K"]` |

The problem is that the numbers can be abritrarly close:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `[950, 1100, 1200, 1300]` | `["1K", "1K", "1K", "1K"]` |

That is the naive approach, of course, and it's bad.

I would like something like:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `[950, 1100, 1200, 1300]` | `["950", "1.1K", "1.2K", "1.3K"]` |

Is there any library that solves the problem above?

Edit:

This is my solution (adding as part of the question after some heat over where it should be):

I don't know if it's optimal or if it breaks for some testcase. Can you find a better solution (As in fewer lines, faster, more consise?)

```js
const numberFormat = n =>  n.toLocaleString(
  "en-US",
  { minimumFractionDigits: 0 }
);
const SUFFIXES = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T"];

const getPrevSuffix = (suffix) => {
  return SUFFIXES[SUFFIXES.indexOf(suffix) - 1] || "";
};

const getSuffix = (value) => {
  const naive = numberFormat(excelRoundPositive(value, -digits(value)));
  const thousands = naive.match(/,.../g)?.length;
  const postfix = SUFFIXES[thousands || 0] ?? "T";
  return postfix;
};
const pows = {
  undefined: 1,
  null: 1,
  "": 1,
  K: 1000,
  k: 1000,
  M: 1000000,
  m: 1000000,
  B: 1000000000,
  b: 1000000000,
  T: 1000000000000,
  t: 1000000000000
};

export const excelRound = (value, power = 1) => {
  const pow = Math.pow(10, power);
  return Math.round(value * pow) / pow;
};

export const excelRoundPositive = (value, power) => {
  if (value === 0) return 0;
  if (value < 0) return -excelRoundPositive(-value, power);
  let pow = power;
  while (excelRound(value, pow) === 0) {
    pow += 1;
  }
  return excelRound(value, pow);
};

const digits = (value) => {
  if (value !== 0) return Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(value)));
  return 0;
};

/**
 * Zero gets formatted as `0`
 * Negative numbers get formatted as positives, with a minus sign
 * Numbers get formatted with X decimals, where X = max(decimal of suffix)
 * is this dYnAmIc ProGrAMmInG
 */
export const formatInContext = (value, context) => {
  const suffix = getSuffix(value);
  const ctxNoZeros = context.filter((a) => a);
  const formatted = ctxNoZeros.map((v) =>
    formatInContextGreedy(v, ctxNoZeros)
  );
  const maxDecimals = Math.max(
    ...formatted.filter(([d, s]) => s === suffix).map(([d, s]) => d)
  );
  const rounded = excelRoundPositive(value / pows[suffix], maxDecimals);
  if (Math.abs(rounded) >= 1)
    return `${excelRoundPositive(value / pows[suffix], maxDecimals)}${suffix}`;
  return `${1000 * rounded}${getPrevSuffix(suffix)}`;
};

const formatInContextGreedy = (
  value,
  context = [],
  decimals = -Math.min(2, digits(value)) // This is, round up to hundreds, if value has enough digits
) => {
  const suffix = getSuffix(value);
  const currentRounding = excelRoundPositive(value / pows[suffix], decimals);
  const isAnyWithSameRounding = context
    .filter((x) => x !== value && getSuffix(x) === suffix)
    .some(
      (v) => excelRoundPositive(v / pows[suffix], decimals) === currentRounding
    );
  if (!isAnyWithSameRounding) return [decimals, suffix];
  return formatInContextGreedy(value, context, decimals + 1);
};


describe("Format Ticks Number That Should Not collide", () => {
  test.each`
    value               | context                               | result
    ${0}                | ${[0, 101, 1428, 1904, 2380, 2856]}   | ${"0"}
    ${476}              | ${[476, 952, 1428, 1904, 2380, 2856]} | ${"500"}
    ${10}               | ${[10, 101, 1428, 1904, 2380, 2856]}  | ${"10"}
    ${1001}             | ${[0, 1000, 1001, 1234, 2000, 2100]}  | ${"1.001K"}
    ${1234}             | ${[0, 1000, 1001, 1234, 2000, 2100]}  | ${"1.234K"}
    ${1000}             | ${[0, 1000, 1001, 1234, 2000, 2100]}  | ${"1K"}
    ${2000}             | ${[0, 1000, 1001, 1234, 2000, 2100]}  | ${"2K"}
    ${2100}             | ${[0, 1000, 1001, 1234, 2000, 2100]}  | ${"2.1K"}
    ${27.3}             | ${[27.3, 29, 30.3, 31.1]}             | ${"27"}
    ${2100000000000000} | ${[2100000000000000]}                 | ${"2100T"}
    ${-1}               | ${[-1]}                               | ${"-1"}
    ${950}              | ${[950, 1100, 1200, 1300]}            | ${"1K"}
    ${950}              | ${[950, 1000, 1200, 1300]}            | ${"950"}
    ${959}              | ${[950, 1040, 1200, 1300]}            | ${"960"}
    ${951}              | ${[900, 920, 950, 951, 990]}          | ${"951"}
    ${841}              | ${[841, 951, 990]}                    | ${"800"}
    ${951}              | ${[841, 951, 990]}                    | ${"950"}
    ${990}              | ${[841, 951, 990]}                    | ${"990"}
    ${950}              | ${[950, 1040, 1200, 1300]}            | ${"950"}
    ${274}              | ${[274, 548, 822, 1105]}              | ${"300"}
    ${274}              | ${[0, 274, 548, 822, 1096, 1370]}     | ${"300"}
    ${1152}             | ${[0, 384, 768, 1152]}                | ${"1K"}
    ${1152}             | ${[384, 768, 1152]}                   | ${"1K"}
  `(
    "Convert $value when found in $context to $result",
    ({ value, context, result }) => {
      expect(formatInContext(value, context)).toBe(result);
    }
  );
});
```

Thanks!